# combine tables into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I turn a list of tables into a data frame?

I have:

```
> (tabs <- list(table(c('a','a','b')),table(c('c','c','b')),table(c()),table(c('b','b'))))
[[1]]

a b 
2 1 

[[2]]

b c 
1 2 

[[3]]
< table of extent 0 >

[[4]]

b 
2
```

I want:

```
> data.frame(a=c(2,0,0),b=c(1,1,2),c=c(0,2,0))
  a b c
1 2 1 0
2 0 1 2
3 0 0 0 
4 0 2 0
```

PS. Please do *not* assume that the tables were created by `table` calls! They were **not**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c_names <- unique(unlist(sapply(tabs, names)))
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tabs, `[`, c_names))
colnames(df) <- c_names
df[is.na(df)]  <- 0
```

Comment: clever, elegant. nice

Answer (score 2):

This assumes the tables are one dimensional.

```
all.names <- unique(unlist(lapply(tabs, names)))
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
  lapply(
    tabs, function(x) as.list(replace(c(x)[all.names], is.na(c(x)[all.names]), 0))
) ) )    
names(df) <- all.names
df
```

There is probably a cleaner way to do this.

```
#   a b c
# 1 2 1 0
# 2 0 1 2
# 3 0 0 0
# 4 0 2 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tabs <- list(table(c('a','a','b')),table(c('c','c','b')),table(c()),table(c('b','b')))


dat.names <- unique(unlist(sapply(tabs, names)))


dat <- matrix(0, nrow = length(tabs), ncol = length(dat.names))
colnames(dat) <- dat.names


for (ii in 1:length(tabs)) {
   dat[ii, ] <- tabs[[ii]][match(colnames(dat), names(tabs[[ii]]) )]
}

dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0

> dat
     a b c
[1,] 2 1 0
[2,] 0 1 2
[3,] 0 0 0
[4,] 0 2 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty clean approach:

```
library(reshape2)
newTabs <- melt(tabs)
newTabs
#   Var1 value L1
# 1    a     2  1
# 2    b     1  1
# 3    b     1  2
# 4    c     2  2
# 5    b     2  4

newTabs$L1 <- factor(newTabs$L1, seq_along(tabs))
dcast(newTabs, L1 ~ Var1, fill = 0, drop = FALSE)
#   L1 a b c
# 1  1 2 1 0
# 2  2 0 1 2
# 3  3 0 0 0
# 4  4 0 2 0
```

This makes use of the fact that there is a `melt` method for `list`s (see `reshape2:::melt.list`) which automatically adds in a variable (L1 for an unnested `list`) that identifies the index of the list element. Since your list has some items which are empty, they won't show up in your melted list, so you need to `factor` the "L1" column, specifying the levels you want. `dcast` takes care of restructuring your output and allows you to specify the desired `fill` value.